# Haskell, list of list of different types, retriving values (frac knapsack prob)

Tags: haskell, knapsack-problem

I am trying to do the fractional knapsack problem in haskell so far I have

Code:

```
{- Input "how much can the knapsack hole <- x" "Possible items in sack [(label, value, weight), ...]" -}
knap x [] = []
knap x y = if length y == 1 then
```

The input list is in the form [([Char], Integer, Integer), ... ] a list of lists of (list of chars, integer, and integer).

My problem is trying to pull out the label, value, and weight of each item that could possibly be put in the knapsack. (pulling values out of the list of lists)

In my prelude> prompt I am doing some trying by doing

ghci output:

```
Prelude> let x = [("label 1", 2, 14), ("label 2", 1, 15)]
Prelude> :t x
x :: [([Char], Integer, Integer)]
Prelude> length x
2
Prelude> x !! 0
("label 1",2,14)
Prelude> x !! 0 !! 1

<interactive>:1:1:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]'
                with actual type `([Char], Integer, Integer)'
    Expected type: [[a0]]
      Actual type: [([Char], Integer, Integer)]
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `x !! 0'
```

As you can see I am trying to do list !! index !! index to try and pull a weight off of a "item". What is the proper syntax to do this?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget the rest of the `if` expression in the first code block?  Also, `[([Char], Integer, Integer)]` is a list of tuples, which is not what you are trying to achieve.  You may be looking for `[[([Char], Integer, Integer)]]` instead.

Comment: If I must allow the input to be a list of tuples, how I might I get the values in the tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `!!` operator only works on lists, as you can see from its type signature: `[a] -> Int -> a`.

If you'd like to stick with tuples, you could define your own functions for 3-tuples in the style of [`fst`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afst) and [`snd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3asnd). You could do this with pattern matching; something like:

```
first :: (a,b,c) -> a
first (a,_,_) = a
```

However, it might be better to design a datatype for an item, and use records to extract the field you need.

```
data Item = Item { label  :: String
                   value  :: Int
                   weight :: Int
                 }
```

Then to make a new item `x` you can use `let x = Item {label = "label 1", value = 2, weight = 14}`

Now you could model your knapsack as a list of items of type `[Item]`, and to get the value of the first item, you could use `value $ knapsack !! 0`, where `knapsack` is your list of items.

Answer (score 2):

`(a,b,c)` is a tuple, not a list. You can't use `!!` on tuples. After all: what would the type of `!!` be for tuples?

The way to get values out of tuple is to use pattern matching like this:

```
let (name, x, y) = theTuple in
-- ...
```

Pattern matching is also usually the preferred way to get at the head of a list. So a function working on a list of tuples would usually look something like this:

```
f [] = -- handle the empty list
f ((name, x, y) : rest) =
  -- do something with name, x and y and then recurse on rest
```